# Java 8 Identifiers/Keywords List

Tags: java, java-8

I've been recently looking at the Java 8 Documentation and was surprised to see so many new identifiers (e.g. Consumer). Can someone please give me a list of these identifiers and what they mean? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation that you were looking at?

Comment: @Cupcake http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html was one of them

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's [just an interface](http://download.java.net/lambda/b81/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).  The keywords should've stayed the same between the two versions; I don't recall them adding anything new to the language as far as keywords are concerned.

Comment: @Makoto I don't remember seeing Consumer before, am I missing something?

Comment: @user3577580: From your post: "[...]was surprised to see so many new identifiers (e.g. Consumer)"

Comment: @PakkuDon I meant before as in Java 7 or below

Comment: It's a new interface, that much is certain.  But that's not really a keyword or identifier; it's more or less a new interface.  You could look at the various JSRs and the changelog to get an idea of what's new...but unless you're looking at/for something specific, there's a lot of stuff to cover.

Comment: @Makoto I tried to cover a few of the basics. If you have more to add, would you mind editing my answer? Thanks!

Comment: @manan:  You don't cover anything related to the new Time API, or Lambdas, or what those identifiers are actually used for.  There's a lot of information that needs to be covered, and I'm not 100% sure that a list-form answer is the best way to convey that.

Comment: [java.util.Consumer](http://download.java.net/lambda/b81/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) is not a keyword, it's an interface, introduced in Java 8 because it can be used in Lamba Expressions.

Comment: @Naili I was confused between the two. Sorry - though I still think that it would be useful to have a list that maps these names to what they "mean"

Comment: @user3577580 There is something else you have to know, that in java naming conventions keywords are all in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a compiled (potentially incomplete) list which includes some of the most common interfaces and their corresponding meanings. Hopefully this helps!

---

**Takes no arguments**: Called a `Supplier`

**Takes a single `int`, `double`, or `long` argument**: Called either

- `IntXX`
- `LongXX`
- `DoubleXX`

**Takes two arguments**: Called a `BiXX`

**Takes two arguments *of the same type***: Called a `binaryOperator`

**Takes two arguments of which the first is a reference type and the second is a primitive type**: Called an `ObjXXConsumer`

**Returns `void`**: Called a `Consumer`

**Returns an `int`, `long`, or `double`**: 
Called either

- `XXToIntYY`
- `XXToLongYY`
- `XXToDoubleYY`

**Returns a `boolean`**: Called a `Predicate`

Otherwise, it's simply called a `Function`

---

Please feel free to add more information to this answer or any identifiers that I missed.

Comment: That covers the `java.util.function` package which is only one of the many changes. See http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html for a more complete list.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) states that "50 character sequences, formed from ASCII letters, are reserved for use as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers."

The full list is:

```
abstract   continue   for          new         switch assert    
default    if           package     synchronized boolean    do        
goto         private     this break      double     implements  
protected   throw byte       else       import       public     
throws case       enum       instanceof   return      transient catch 
extends    int          short       try char       final     
interface    static      void class      finally    long        
strictfp    volatile const      float      native       super      
while
```

These do not include names of interfaces like `Consumer`, however.